# Nexus 5 Update: Will I Lose Root?

Tags: root-access

I'm currently rooted but didn't do anything to my Nexus 5. It's just rooted but it's on its stock ROM. My question is, on the next Android update, will I lose root? Will the update just erase root permission and update? If not, how can I unroot?

I rooted my Nexus 5 in one click using RT Root tool or something, TR Root for Nexus. It's an app. It didn't work very well, some apps still didn't work. Is there an app that can completely delete ROOT before I update? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update via Android's Over-The-Air (OTA) Update, you will lose root. You will need to re-root again if you want root access,

Comment: Chainfire's SuperSU has a 'retain root' option in it for some firmwares. Whether it works on a case by case basis like this is probably very variable.

Comment: @RossC I'm not aware of any setting in the SuperSU app. Would you know which one this is? I'm guessing `Survival mode`, but I haven't tried this yet. I always keep it unchecked.

Comment: Sorry, survival mode is the name. It worked one time and not since. It's a case by case basis.

Comment: @RossC Ever since the OTA RootKeeper app stopped working, I "believed" that this feature would no longer be work for more recent versions (4.3 and higher). But again, I've not tried this with S4 Android 4.4. I flash custom ROMs with root access now.

Comment: Looked into it, Survival mode isn't really working for newer versions. I also flash Pre rooted ROMs myself!

Comment: Thanks guys. So far I used Temp Unroot option in SuperSu and it works like a charm. No root access as long as that option is selected. And I will update my device over the air, like a carrier update and will delete root automatically as far as I know.